# Clonezilla , NLite and PCs with different hardware specs

Tags: clonezilla, nlite

I used Clonezilla to create and restore images from a master computer to other workstations with the same specs, but the problem now is there are new computers whose hardware specs are different than the ones I maintained (mostly the video card is different).

Is it possible to create a customize Windows XP installer using Nlite and integrate all potential video card and motherboard drivers? If I then used this NLite ISO to install to a master computer which I will later clone and restore the image to other workstations, will Windows XP still pick up the correct driver set?

During XP installation, does the Windows installer transfers all the drivers to the computer's hard disk?

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to sysprep the machine with a custom sysprep.inf and add something like below.

```
OemPnPDriversPath = Sysprep\drivers\audio\analog_devices\hd;Sysprep\drivers\audio\analog_devices\ac97;Sysprep\drivers\audio\realtek\hd;Sysprep\drivers\audio\realtek\ac97;Sysprep\drivers\audio\sigmatel;Sysprep\drivers\bluetooth\toshiba;Sysprep\drivers\bluetooth\widcomm
```

Then after sysprepping you image the machine.

Comment: If your doing Win7 deployments, sysprepping is far superior to cloning. Windows 7 is pretty good about finding basic drivers for pretty much anything. Combine Sysprep with PXE booting and you dont even need to find your thumbdrive/DVDs anymore. Huge time saver!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all preloaded drivers slipstreamed using Nlite will be installed during installation. What I'm not of is if this will cause a conflict if you are installing multiple drivers, I have the inclination that it wouldn't since the the drivers that would be in use would be for the hardware that is currently there.

Answer (score 0):

Try Driver Packs, it will bloat the install disc to DVD size if you include all driver packs.

http://driverpacks.net/

Tutorial for using Driver Packs Base software, read carefully.

http://forum.driverpacks.net/viewtopic.php?id=1449

.

If you do use Nlite, be sure to use it first, then use Driverppacks base last or there will be problems during installation.

.

There is Paragon software that can clone>migrate and installation to new hardware. See scenario 3, I don't think it installs drivers, but will allow it to be bootable in the new system.

.

http://www.paragon-software.com/home/dc-personal/